# Complex MySQL query selecting all items which have all attributes

Tags: mysql, sql

I got the following schema:

```
employees(emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name,...)  
departments(dept_no, dept_name)  
dept_emp(emp_no, dept_no)
```

and I am trying to find a query that returns  the first and last name and employee number of the employees that have worked in all departments. Any ideas?

P.S.: emp_no and dept_no are the primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    e.emp_no
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN dept_emp dn ON dn.emp_no = e.
INNER JOIN departments d ON d.dept_no = dn.dept_no
```